# How do I parallelize my Sapply function using a big.matrix? ( object of type 'S4' is not subsettable error)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, sapply

first post/question so apologies if I do anything wrong, just let me know and ill fix it.
I am trying to use parsapply to implement a function that gets the mean of a weighted vector (just using mean to make it work i wish to be able to do other stuff, but the mean for now) but I keep receiving this error :

```
4 nodes produced errors; first error: object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

I am using a big.matrix called PUBG_stats and trying to implement it on the 8th column and a partitioning vector called partition in the code below, how do I convert my data from S4 to a class that works or is there another way to do this? Ive use R a good bit but I am new to parallel.

```
library(parallel)
ncores<-detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(ncores-1) 
clusterExport(cl, c("PUBG_stats","partition"))
system.time(parLapply(cl, 1:4, loopi, y=x1, partid=partid1))
parSapply(cl,1:5,function(x)(sum(PUBG_stats[,8][partition==1]*rand_vec(length(PUBG_stats[,8][partition==1]),N))/N))
```

ran_vec is just some function creating weights, and the 1:5 is there as i want to repeat it 1:r times whatever r needed.

A reproducible example that has the same issue would be the below:

```
library(bigmemory)
library(parallel)
a<- as.big.matrix(rnorm(100000))
ncores <- detectCores()  
cl <- makeCluster(ncores) 
clusterExport(cl, c("a","sum","rnorm"))

parSapply(cl,1:5,function(x)(sum(a[,]*rnorm(1))))

stopcluster(cl)
```

error:

```
    object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

Comment: I think you need to add all libraries you use classes or functions from to the clusters: `clusterExport(cl, c("PUBG_stats","partition","bigmemory"))`

Comment: thanks for your reply, Unfortunately that doesn't work, the error that comes up: is object 'bigmemory' not found. I didnt know you had to clusterexport libraries ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example. There are lots of variables there that we don't have access to in order to run your code.

Comment: I have added a basic example that has the same issue that you can run, thanks.

Comment: @karo, to attach packages on the workers, one needs to use e.g. `clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(bigmemory) })`.  It's only objects (e.g. variables and functions) can be exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to load all packages needed also on the workers, which you can do by using `clusterEvalQ()`, e.g.

```r
library(bigmemory)
library(parallel)
a <- as.big.matrix(rnorm(100000))

## Setup workers
ncores <- 2
cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
clusterExport(cl, c("a","sum","rnorm"))
ignore <- clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(bigmemory) })

res <- parSapply(cl, 1:5, function(x) { sum(a[,]*rnorm(1)) })

stopcluster(cl)
```

However, if we try to run the above code, we'll get:

```r
> res <- parSapply(cl, 1:5, function(x) { sum(a[,]*rnorm(1)) })
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  5 nodes produced errors; first error: external pointer is not valid
```

This is because objects of class `big.matrix` *cannot* be exported to other R processes (here workers).  That is a limitation in how those objects work.  There is no solution to this as far as I know - if there was, it would be the author of **bigmatrix** could solve it.

Comment: There seems to be a method `attach.big.matrix` to access an object in clusters. Not sure how to use that in `parSapply`, I'll try to find out when I have time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll just have to work around that issue so. Do you know if the ff package has the same issue or could it be used instead?

Comment: Sorry I should have tried the ff package before asking about it . If i just use ff it seems to work with all my code so that's great! Thanks again to all that helped, its a bit frustrating that bigmemory doesn't work but I suppose you cant have it all.

Comment: FWIW, in M. Kane, J. Emerson, and S. Weston. Scalable strategies for computing with massive data. Journal of Statistical Software, Articles, 55(14):1–19, 2013. ISSN 1548-7660. doi: 10.18637/jss.v055.i14. <https://www.jstatsoft.org/v055/i14>, the authors have a section on 'Combining bigmemory and foreach'.  The authors are also the developers of those packages.